# Improve access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote a query in access but i don't know if its alright (it works) and as my c++ programer friend says "it works then its fine", but i'm new to sql and i like to improve, and not hammer the thing down.

My code consists in transform a column rows into columns and retrieve the total of discount per product according the discount criteria.

```
TRANSFORM sum(c.[min value# %]) AS sum_min_value
SELECT c.supplier, c.sku, c.dept, c.UN, a.BRAND, sum(c.[min value# %]) AS 
Total_of_discount
FROM (SELECT a.*, d.* FROM price AS a LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CGF AS b 
   WHERE (b.variable="cmp" and b.order="1"))  AS d ON IIf(d.brand="-",(Not 
   ((d.[structure exclusion]=cstr(a.dept)) Or (d.[structure 
   exclusion]=cstr(a.un)))) And (d.structure=a.dept Or d.structure=a.un Or 
   d.structure=25) And (a.supplier=d.[# supplier]),(Not ((d.[structure 
   exclusion]=cstr(a.dept)) Or (d.[structure exclusion]=cstr(a.un)))) And 
   (d.structure=a.dept Or d.structure=a.un Or d.structure=25) And 
   (a.supplier=d.[# supplier]) And (d.brand=a.brand) And Not (d.[brand 
   exclusion]=a.brand)))  AS c
GROUP BY c.supplier, c.sku, c.dept, c.un, a.BRAND
PIVOT c.[HEADING CGF];
```

The part that i have more doubts is the if statement. can you help pls. ty

Comment: If you don't have a specific problem and just want some feedback, you may want to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how the "ON" would work.  Please post a sample output row from this query.

I am expecting to see "a.somecolumn1 = d.somecolumn2).

But what I see is IIF x then followed by a pair of similar logic clauses.  What are the two alternative join statements that are to be used?

```
TRANSFORM SUM(c.[min value# %]) AS sum_min_value
SELECT c.supplier,
       c.sku,
       c.dept,
       c.un,
       a.brand,
       SUM(c.[min value# %]) AS Total_of_discount
FROM   (SELECT a.*,
               d.*
        FROM      price AS a
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                   FROM   cgf AS b
                   WHERE  ( b.variable = "cmp" AND b.ORDER = "1" )
                  ) AS d

        ON Iif(d.brand = "-", ( NOT ( ( d.[structure exclusion] = Cstr(a.dept) )
                                    OR( d.[structure exclusion] = Cstr(a.un) ) ) )
                                  AND ( d.structure = a.dept
                                     OR d.structure = a.un
                                     OR d.structure = 25 )

                                  AND ( a.supplier = d.[# supplier] )
                            ,

                              ( NOT ( ( d.[structure exclusion] = Cstr(a.dept) )
                                   OR ( d.[structure exclusion] = Cstr(a.un) ) ) )
                                  AND ( d.structure = a.dept
                                     OR d.structure = a.un
                                     OR d.structure = 25 )

                                  AND ( a.supplier = d.[# supplier] )

                                  AND ( d.brand = a.brand )
                              AND NOT ( d.[brand exclusion] = a.brand ))
        ) AS c

GROUP  BY c.supplier,
          c.sku,
          c.dept,
          c.un,
          a.brand
PIVOT c.[HEADING CGF];
```

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426780/transform-row-variables-into-columns-and-fill-them-according-to-condition), here is my first question since nobody helped i updated the question to give the answer but let stay the problem if it helps...ty

Comment: The prior link CGF table the same supplier 12445 getting three different Percents.  And does not show any table PRICE rows.  And the "output" includes a SEQ_NO that is not in the sql.  We must see correct sample table data for both inputs and for expected output.!!!  We probably cannot help you.